# Are there other ways than functions in selects to check for specific values?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT *
FROM DOCUMENTS
WHERE STATUS IN (1, 2, 3);
```

I need some way to keep track where in code these 3 statuses are checked. One option would be to check them through a function. Then, if I needed to add another status in these same queries, I could just add it in the function. But that makesthe query slow. Are there any other ways how to do it?

I know of SQL macros since 19.7 but we only have 19.0

Comment: A general way to store the data in DBMS is obviously a table

Answer (score 2):

Keep them in a separate table:

```
create table status (id_status) as
  select 1 from dual union all
  select 2 from dual union all
  select 3 from dual;

alter table status add constraint pk_status primary key (id_status);
```

Modify current query to

```
SELECT *
FROM DOCUMENTS
WHERE STATUS IN (select status from status);
```

Once new status appears, just

```
insert into status (id_status) values (4);
```

and all queries - that reference statuses - will still keep working and won't have to be modified.